# config.logger and config.paths.log in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, logging

I get this error when trying to start the server.

```
logger.rb:541:in `exist?': can't convert Rails::Paths::Path into String (TypeError)
```

This is the code in my development.rb.

```
require 'log_formatter'
config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first)
config.logger.formatter = LogFormatter.new
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

I have tried adding .to_s, but it's no use.

Google is no help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first.path)`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Paths/Path.html

Comment: Nope. It fails with the same message.

Comment: The problem, as stated by the error message, is that the method `exist?` expects a string, and you're not passing in a string, but a `Rails::Paths::Path`. What does your call to `to_s` show? Are there many paths being stored in the `Rails::Paths::Path`?

Comment: When I do to_s, I still get the same message... I am however suspecting that it is something completely different.

Comment: Wow, that was amazingly stupid... I was editing the wrong environment file... That's what happens when you code while tired...

Comment: The correct line is.     config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first)    In the right file..

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 3.1.1 the old syntax has been deprecated. You should now use:

```
config.paths['log'].first
```