# log method is undefined in config.paths.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to limit the log size and put this line

`config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first, 1, 5.megabytes)`

in **development.rb**

No luck, I got  undefined method error

```
config.paths.log
NoMethodError: undefined method `log' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fa5c1de7308>
```

#### dumped `config.paths`

```
[3] pry(#<COT::Application>)> config.paths
#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fa5c1de7308 @current=nil, 
... 
"log"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x007fa5c1de5c38 @paths=["log/development.log"], @current="log", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x007fa5c1de7308 ...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
config.paths['log'].first
```

instead of

```
config.paths.log.first
```

Ref: [config.logger and config.paths.log in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268525/config-logger-and-config-paths-log-in-rails-3)